# angular-ui-layout - adding drag ended/panel resized event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I'm working with the [angular-ui-layout plugin](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout/blob/master/src/ui-layout.js)

That link is the source code, on line 211 there is the following code to handle `mouseup`:

```
    htmlElement.on('mouseup touchend', function () {
      htmlElement.off('mousemove touchmove');
    });
```

I need to slip a callback in there:

```
    htmlElement.on('mouseup touchend', function () {
       htmlElement.off('mousemove touchmove');
       scope.onDragEnd();
    });
```

In order to respond to this event outside the plugin:

```
   <div ui-layout on-drag-end="vm.layoutResized()"> ... </div>
```

However, I can't seem to make the neccesary changes for `vm.layoutResized()` to get fired.

I tried adding something like the following to the scope on one or both of the directives:

```
      scope: {
          onDragEnd: '&'
      }
```

But `vm.layoutResized()` doesn't get called. Can someone look at the link source and tell me how to pass this function through the nested scopes so that it's defined where I call it?

Comment: I didn't see a directive for on-drag-end in the angularJS ui-layout plugin. How does that work with on-drag-end in the HTML? Do you have a custom directive for that?

Comment: No, I'm trying to bind the function through that attribute to the scope of the `ui-layout` directive. That's what the included `scope: { onDragEnd: '&' }` is for. I've passed options like this to a directive before just never a function. However I've seen it done somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to modify the angular-ui-layout plugin/directive

Add a function in uiLayoutCtrl which should internally call another directive level scope variable and that should intern execute the layoutResize.

```
  //Method called from actual resize event
  triggerResize: function (eve) {
      $scope.resize(eve);
  }


//External facing method that will be called
  scope: {
      'resize': '&onResize'
  },

//Usage
<div ui-layout on-resize="ResizeFn()">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sjsingh/DJqfZ/1/

Added updated angular-ui-layout code in this link.

Answer (score 3):

I also had problem that required a change in one of the ui-layout directive 'uiSplitbar'
But instead to change it directly I using override ,set the priority of my directive that it will run after the base directive.

I wrote a post how I handle a problem with angular ui-layout, see link below

[Using angular ui-layout](https://orenw.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/using-angular-ui-layout/)

Comment: nice technique with the priority -1. I ended up modifying the source for this problem but I will definitely try that technique another time.

Answer (score 1):

Change your attribute in the directive from this:

```
  scope: {
      onDragEnd: '&'
  }
```

To this:

```
  scope: {
      'drag-end': '&onDragEnd'
  }
```

see the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ngdoc:example-example89@snapshot?p=preview

I saw this format in the section on [Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements) from the AngularJS documentation on directives.